# MVC viewmodel constructors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it good practice to populate the models/variables of a viewmodel in the constructor of the viewmodel?

For instance:

```
public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Programme> ProgramList { get; set; }
    public string QuerystringAgeID { get; set; }

    public ProgramViewModel()
    {
        QuerystringAgeID = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["QuerystringAgeID"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it good practice to populate the models/variables of a viewmodel in
>   the constructor of the viewmodel?

It depends.

But with the example you have shown, the answer is **no**. You have a model binder that is supposed to do that:

```
public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Programme> ProgramList { get; set; }
    public string QuerystringAgeID { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Foo(ProgramViewModel model)
{
    // model.QuerystringAgeID will be automatically populated 
    // with the value of the QuerystringAgeID 
    // thanks to the default model binder
    ...
}
```

In addition to that you should absolutely avoid using `HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET MVC application. Makes your code tied to an ASP.NET context making it impossible to reuse and unit test in isolation. ASP.NET MVC provides you abstractions for this: HttpContextBase, ...